# Need help: Multiple Listing channels with one template. DRY

Tags: templating

I have several Listing channels that all use the same templates:

E.g.

Templates:

- /templates/view/overview.html
- /templates/view/detail.html

Channels

- News
- Research Updates
- Upcoming Events

How can I only list the entries for each channel at their respective URL without having to duplicate the templates?

E.g.

"http://mysite.com/news" should only list the the latest 20 news stories with links to the detail page.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news', 'research', 'events').limit(20).find() %}
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2 class="Heading"><a href="{{ entry.url }}" title="{{ entry.title }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
    <p class="Date">{{entry.postDate|date('M j, Y')}}</p>
    <p>{{ excerpt|length > 250 ? excerpt|slice(0, 200) ~ '...' : excerpt  }}</p>
    <p><a href="{{ entry.url }}" title="{{ entry.title }}" class="ReadMore">Read More</a></p>
</div>
```

{% endfor %}

Answer (score 3):

A good option here is to make use of [craft.request](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request). As long as the URL is the section handle, you can do something like this:

```
{% current_section = craft.request.firstSegment %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section(current_section).limit(20).find() %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

If the url is mysite.com/news, `firstSegment` will return 'news', which you can use in your `craft.entries` call.

**UPDATE:**

If your URLs need to be different than the section handles, make use of Twig's [include with](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html#include) tag. For each section, you will need an index.html template with the following:

```
{% set current_section = 'thisSectionHanle' %}
{% include listPage.html with current_section %}
```

listPage.html can be the template that has the actual fetch and display logic. Using `include with`, listPage.html will have access to the `current_section` variable.

So not *perfectly* dry, but the main logic chunk will not have to be repeated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This will work for the 'news' section but it does not work when I have sections with handles like 'reasearchUpdates'. Craft does not allow dashes in section names. My url for these entries would like something like mysite.com/research-updates/this-is-the-title

Comment: Just updated with another option!